# Is it natural to say "the seller is calling out loud to advertise her products"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

[image]

In some developing countries, some sellers walk/ride on streets and call out loud to advertise their products and attract customers.

They often sell traditional food or ice cream. In the past they used their actual voice, which could make them exhausted. Now they use recorders with loud speakers, which save their energy.

Is it natural to say "**the seller is calling out loud to advertise her products**"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your suggestion is perfectly understandable, but there are a few special words  for this in English. The first is *hawk*.

Bing gives this definition,

> carry around and offer (goods) for sale, typically advertising them by shouting.

This word isn't much used in the US these days, but it's easily understood. It's well known in Singapore, for example, although there it refers to selling items from fixed outdoor stalls rather than while walking around. A person who sells things this way is called a *hawker*.

Another related term is to *tout*,

> attempt to sell (something), typically by pestering people in an aggressive or bold manner.

Again, I'm more familiar with this word from a few visits to Singapore than from a lifetime in the US, although most Americans would probably understand it with context.

And there is a somewhat old-fashioned use of the word *cry*,

> (of a street trader) shout out the name of (goods for sale).

For example you could say the trader in your picture is "crying her goods". There is even a Wikipedia article about these historical [street cries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Street_cries).

So, for example, you could say

- The woman walked the streets hawking tomatoes and garlic.
- As she walked she touted her goods.
- She carried tomatoes and garlic through the streets, crying her wares as she went.

Comment: We still say that street or market sellers 'cry their wares'.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey, Living in the US, I've never seen the term come up, except in historical contexts. Maybe in other countries, it's still current.

Comment: The Photon - the municipal code of the City of Haverhill, Essex County, Massachusetts, Section 191-1, of 1980, says "No person hawking, peddling or carrying or exposing any articles for sale shall cry his wares to the disturbance of the peace and the comfort of the inhabitants of the City nor otherwise than in vehicles or receptacles which are neat and clean and do not leak." The expression is common in municipal codes across the US.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey, 1. Since there's a law against it, it probably doesn't happen much, leading to the term not being used often in daily conversation. 2. Legal usages contain many terms and usages that are obsolete in daily conversation because they have well-established meaning in the law even after they've dropped out of use in conversation. 3. Just because the law was written in 1980 doesn't mean it wasn't copied verbatim from earlier laws.

Comment: You can cry your wares in Haverhill as long as you do it quietly using a neat, clean, non-leaking vehicle or receptacle.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey, Even archaic terms get used sometimes. And I never said this was archaic, only  "somewhat old fashioned".

Comment: The concept isn't totally obsolete. People walk around my neighborhood ringing a bell to announce they're selling ice cream from a push cart. But I've never heard anybody call this "crying their wares" (even if there might be a law using that term that has been established by precedent to legally encompass this activity). In daily speech we come up with some other way to describe this activity.

Comment: If someone pushed a cart along my street shouting "Hot Dogs! Burgers!" I'd rush out (with my face mask on, natch) and buy something. I might very well say to my wife "I heard him crying his wares", and expect to be understood.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey, you are an educated English speaker who answers questions here. If the same situation happened to 100 of your neighbors, and you asked them about it later, how many of them do you think would use the phrase "crying his wares" to describe it? (And, once again, I called the phrase "somewhat oldfashioned", not "obsolete" or "archaic". And even if it were archaic, your wife very well might understand it, just as she would understand what you meant if you started addressing her with "thee" and "thou")

Comment: @MichaelHarvey, In any case I don't see this discussion becoming productive. Maybe where you live, the phrase "crying their wares" is entirely common and used every day. Where I live it is considered old fashioned, and only used extremely rarely. If you want to add an answer saying  how the picture would be described by someone from Haverhill Mass., please do so.